# How to merge synthesis results in Vivado

Tags: fpga, xilinx, synthesis, vivado, netlist

I have a Vivado design with embedded Block Design. It creates circa 150 out of context runs (synthesis) and a final synthesis run. Unfortunately, the final synthesis run contains only a top-level wrapper and black boxes.

I would like to get the final top-level DCP and all out-of-context run DCPs merged into one big DCP. This can then be used as an input for a standalone implementation run in my CI environment.

How can I merge all these DCPs into one big DCP?

---

DCP = Design Check Point

Comment: It's amazing how much context helps. UG904 Vivado Design Suite User Guide **Beginning the Implementation Flow** "• In Non-Project Mode, you use the link_design command to load the design." You can safely say it's in the documentation. The only problem is there's thousands of lines of documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load all the checkpoints into Vivado using read_checkpoint and then link them together with link_design. After that you can write out a unified checkpoint:

```
read_dcp top.dcp
read_dcp child0.dcp
...
read_dcp child149.dcp
link_design
write_checkpoint unified.dcp
```